# Как считать содержимое файла в формате PDF в виде картинки на C#

Tags: c#, winforms, .net

Как считать содержимое PDF в виде картинки на C#? Пытался это сделать через itextsharp.dll,
открыл pdf при помощи PdfReader. Как сделать так, чтобы можно было полностью считать страницу pdf как одно целое изображение и потом вывести его в WinForms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно сначала преобразовать pdf в jpg/png с помощью imagemagic (либо из командной строки, либо через связки с .NET - MagicNet), а уже затем считать полученные файлы изображений в .NET и отобразить на форме. Преобразование pdf в jpg/png

```
convert sample.pdf sample.png
```

Загрузить и вывести полученную картинку можно через Image/PictureBox, например.

```
Image i = Image.FromFile("Sample.jpg");

e.Graphics.DrawImage(i, new Point(0, 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

Растеризация векторной страницы PDF документа в растровую картинку bmp/jpeg/png высокого качества - задача достаточно сложная (я использовал в проекте [Apitron.PDF.Rasterizer](http://blog.apitron.com/2013/06/convert-pdf-to-image-csharp-dotnet-sample.html))

Не рекламирую, но код получился достаточно компактный (делал нечто похожее с iTextSharp получился монстроподобный код), полностью managed не нужно дергать плюсовае dll или сторонние апликухи, по производительности получили хорошие результаты (когда распараллелили по ядрам получили 30% выигрыш). Также на этой же библиотеке сделали сервис для телефонов (поддержка WinRT, WindowsPhone 8, Xamarin.iOS / Android) включена в либу.